# How can i store files in sessions such i can acces it during one complete session period?

Tags: php, session

How to store the files in session variables so that i can use those sessions in next step of form wizard?
like this

```
   $_SESSION['fileupload']=$_FILES['fileupload'];
```

Comment: Why store all of it in a session? Try to store only the filename or the path.

Comment: i am using multiple file upload then how to store all file names in sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Store the file on the server when you upload it, then in the session store the filename/path which will allow you to use the file on the next step of your wizard.

Storing the file contents in a session is pointless and will drain resources on the server.

Comment: i am using multiple file upload then how to store all file names in sessions?

Comment: i need to store all the data in database only after the final step so how to do so

Comment: Store the file names in the session as an array.

    $_SESSION['files'] = array('file1.txt','file2.txt');

Then when you want to access the files just loop around the session array with a foreach:

    foreach($_SESSION['files'] as $file) {
        echo $file;
    }